# Android Custom Notification with RemoteView is not showing properly blow Nougat OS

Tags: android, push-notification, android-6.0-marshmallow, remoteview

I m trying to create a custom notification using `RemoteView`. It is showing properly in Nougat and above OS version devices but has an issue with marshmallow and below OS version devices.

[image]

Here is default Big icon (Left side inside the Red circle) and default time (In Right side red circle) is not hiding after Remote view.

Please suggest me how I can come out of this problem.

```
private void sendNotification() {
    Long id = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int notifyId = id.intValue();

    RemoteViews expandedView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.view_expanded_notification);
    expandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.timestamp, DateUtils.formatDateTime(this, System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME));
    expandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_message, mEditText.getText());
    // adding action to left button
    Intent leftIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationIntentService.class);
    leftIntent.setAction("left");
    expandedView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.left_button, PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, leftIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    // adding action to right button
    Intent rightIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationIntentService.class);
    rightIntent.setAction("right");
    expandedView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.right_button, PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, rightIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

    RemoteViews collapsedView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.view_collapsed_notification);
    collapsedView.setTextViewText(R.id.timestamp, DateUtils.formatDateTime(this, System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME));

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "imp")
            // these are the three things a NotificationCompat.Builder object requires at a minimum
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_pawprint)
            .setContentTitle(NOTIFICATION_TITLE)
            .setContentText(CONTENT_TEXT)
            // notification will be dismissed when tapped
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            // tapping notification will open MainActivity
            .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0))
            // setting the custom collapsed and expanded views
            .setCustomContentView(collapsedView)
            .setCustomBigContentView(expandedView)
            // setting style to DecoratedCustomViewStyle() is necessary for custom views to display
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle());

    // retrieves android.app.NotificationManager

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("imp", "Test", importance);
        channel.setDescription("For testing");
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        notificationManager.notify(notifyId, builder.build());
    } else {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (android.app.NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }

}
```

This is properly shown in Nougat and above devices.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, id);

```
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notification)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setCustomBigContentView(remoteExpandedViews)
            .setCustomContentView(remoteCollapsedViews)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            **.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)**
            .setVibrate(new long[]{0});
```

set Priority to PRIORITY_MAX using .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX) in builder